# SELECT from one table, based on join of two others

Tags: sql

I would like to

Select columns from table a
Where extension table a  =  extension in table b
And department in both table b and table c match 
Based on that match that deptartment in table c should = yes

```
Select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5  from table a
   Where col2 table a = col2 table b
   And  col3 in table b = col3 in table c
   And  col4 tabel c = yes
```

can anyone help.

Comment: Is this really the query you're trying to use? I suggest familiarizing yourself with SQL syntax.

Comment: That does not make any sense. Please show example data and expected output

Comment: Select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5  from table a
Where col2 table a = col2 table b
And  col3 in table b = col3 in table c
And  col4 tabel c = yes

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is ambiguous have you tried:

```
SELECT A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, A.COL4, A.COL5
FROM TABLE_A A
JOIN TABLE_B B
ON A.Extension = B.Extension
JOIN TABLE_C C
ON B.Department = C.Department
AND C.Department = 'yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in different ways. As following:

Way 1

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 
FROM tableA 
JOIN tableB ON tableA.col2 = tableB.col2
JOIN tableC ON tableB.col3 = tableC.col3 AND tableC.col4 = 'yes'
```

Way 2

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 
FROM tableA 
JOIN tableB ON tableA.col2 = tableB.col2
JOIN tableC ON tableB.col3 = tableC.col3
WHERE tableC.col4 = 'yes'
```

Way 3

```
SELECT * 
INTO #col4yesTable
FROM tableC
Where col4 = 'yes'

SELECT tableA.col1, tableA.col2, tableA.col3, tableA.col4, tableA.col5 
FROM #col4yesTable
JOIN tableB ON #col4yesTable.col3 = tableB.col3
JOIN tableB ON tableA.col2 = tableB.col2
```

Depends on your need you can use one of them. The last one, creates a temporary table to store all tableC objects that has col4 = 'yes'